# Eclipse 4 RPC - converting IEclipsePreferences to IPreferenceStore?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp

Why Eclipse has `org.eclipse.jface.preference.PreferenceStore` and if i want to use Eclipse 4 RCP, which is based on `jface` and some eclipse runtime, than i need to use `org.osgi.service.prefs.Preferences` instances accessible via `ConfigurationScope.INSTANCE`?

I need to save some config for my jface based UI (SourceViewer), which is already implemented and is using `IPreferenceStore`.

So how i should save my config? Save it via `ConfigurationScope.INSTANCE` and than implement custom `IPreferenceStore` on top of it or how?

I was even thinking about using my own `.properties` file and than pass it to the `PreferenceStore` constructor, but i am not sure than where i should place that `.properties` file (in what directory?)

That Eclipse 4 looks for me a bit incompatible with it self.

Answer (score 0):

It is not all that clear what your question is, here is some relevant information

```java
ConfigurationScope.INSTANCE.getNode("node id")
```

gives you `IEclipsePreference` stored in the 'configuration' subdirectory of the RCP installation directory.

```java
InstanceScope.INSTANCE.getNode("node id")
```

gives the preferences stored in the instance location in the .metadata/plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings directory. The instance location is what Eclipse 3.x calls the workspace.

In Eclipse 3.x the `IPreferenceStore` for a plugin is actually

```java
new ScopedPreferenceStore(InstanceScope.INSTANCE, "plugin id");
```

but `ScopedPreferenceStore` is not available in e4 (unless you copy the source code).

Comment: I have that ConfigurationScope saved in subdirectory .metadata/plugin/org.eclipse.pde.core/bc.product/.settings/xxx.pref of my workspace.

Comment: I wanted to know how to use ConfigurationScope if i need to have my config accessible via PreferenceStore instance. Should i than avoid the ConfigurationScope? Or implement IPreferenceStore on top of ConfigurationScope?